# Change domain name on OpenCMS website

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, opencms

I have bought website running on an OpenCMS and I've migrated the database to my own system. However, I would like to keep the original version running on `old.` subdomain. And here's the problem:

- original opencms domain was `www.example.org` (app) and `rs.example.org` (admin panel), now, it's where new webapp is running.
- openCMS should be running on `old.example.org`
- httpd on the server (port 80) is configured to redirect requests to tomcat (localhost:8080), `/etc/hosts` has hardcoded 127.0.0.1 for `www.example.org` and `rs.example.org`
- OpenCMS config `opencms-system.xml` contains the following:

  `<sites>
      <workplace-server>http://rs.example.org</workplace-server>
      <default-uri>/sites/default/</default-uri>
      <shared-folder>/shared/</shared-folder>
      <site server="http://rs.example.org" uri="/sites/default/"/>
      <site server="http://www.example.org" uri="/sites/www.example.org/"  />
  </sites>`

I tried to simply change "server" attribute in XML config and modify hosts (change `www.` to `old.`).

Result was not what I was expecting - webapplication has started, but totally different template has been used (different html output for homepage).

Any ideas, what to do to be able to run the same application with only the domain change?

Application runs on gentoo server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is working :)

```
        <site server="http://www.example.org" uri="/sites/www.example.org/">
            <alias server="http://old.example.org"/>
        </site>
```